# How to change the name of the property in Vuejs Computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Building a VUEJS project -  I have computed property being returned from the store. An array of objects.
I want to rename the property name coming from the store (which, behind the scenes is fetching from the API)

For example: What I am getting the response from store/API

```
    {
        "f1": "John",
        "f2": "Doe", 
        "f3": "School",
    },
    {
        "f1": "Michael",
        "f2": "John",
        "f3": "College",
    }
]
```

What I want it to be in the data

```
[
    {
        "Nom": "John",
        "Prenom": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "Nom": "Michael",
        "Prenom": "John"
    }
]
```

I want the computed property to be formatted the way I want it to be.
Also, to remove any unwanted properties coming from the response.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
computed: {
  formatted() {
    return json.map(item => ({
      Nom: item.f1,
      Prenom: item.f2
    }));
  }
}
```